# C# Calling focus on text box in SelectedIndexChange event of Listview loses focus on event completion

Tags: c#, listview, focus

I have a listview and when I click on an item, it calls the SelectedIndexChange event, in that event I want to set the focus on a textbox so I call:

this.ActiveControl = theTextBoxControl;

I can see the focus switch to the text box for a split second but focus returns to the listview as soon as the event completes.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably create and set a flag to true, eg: `needToFocusTextBox`. And then do the following in the onFocus event of the ListView.

```
if (needToFocusTextBox)
    this.ActiveControl = theTextBoxControl;
```

Alternatively you could assign the onFocus handler in your SlectedIndexChange event. Then remove it once you have handled onfocus

Comment: This works but I would rather not have a global variable if I can help it.  If I can't figure anything else out I'll go with this.

Comment: @Scott Chantry, I have added an alternative solution to my answer. It doesn't use a global variable.